# How to make two returns in a readonly property in C#?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to return two things in a readonly property?So for example in this property I want to return the first _identifier in the list **OR** an empty string

```
public class IdentifiableObject
{
    private List<string> _identifiers;

    public IdentifiableObject(string[] idents)
    {
    }
  
    public string FirstID
    {
        get
        {
              return ? _identifiers[0] : String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible yes, but it somewhat goes against the principle of least astonishment to implement the logic in the getter of a property.

Comment: [?: operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easy:

```
public string FirstID
{
    get
    {
        return condition ? _identifiers[0] : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Or

```
public string FirstID => condition ? _identifiers[0] : String.Empty;
```

You did not explain what the condition is, so I've just popped a variable in there.

This is perhaps what you wanted:

```
public string FirstID => _identifiers?.Any() ? _identifiers.First() : String.Empty;
```

Comment: Or slightly simpler (IMO): `public string FirstID => _identifiers.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;`

Comment: @BrootsWaymb: Most likely does not matter in reality but there's a difference if identifiers[0] is null.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb: I think `_identifiers.DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty).First();` should work

Answer (score 0):

`first _identifier in the list OR an empty string` - assuming your condition is the array needs to be non null and contain an item -

```
public string FirstID
{
    get
    {
        return _identifiers?.Any() == true ? _identifiers[0] : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.ElementAtOrDefault(0)` with the `??` operator to validate the existing first element.

```cs
    public class IdentifiableObject
    {
        private List<string> _identifiers;

        public IdentifiableObject(string[] idents)
        {
            _identifiers = idents.ToList();
        }

        public string FirstID => _identifiers.ElementAtOrDefault(0) ?? string.Empty;
    }
```

... same applies for `.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty`

Working example can be found here: [dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9h6FIT)

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you can return conditional value in readonly properties
But is better to use DefaultIfEmpty Method

```
public class IdentifiableObject
{
    private List<string> _identifiers;

    public IdentifiableObject(string[] idents)
    {
        
    }
  
    public string FirstID
    {
        get
        {
            
              return _identifiers?.FirstOrDefault()??string.Empty;
        }
    }
    
}
```

[see microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Did you test this before posting? `CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'`

Comment: Yeah I don't assume it's!

Comment: But You can use  `_identifiers?.FirstOrDefault()??string.Empty`;